# chrome local extension via group policy

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a small chrome extension intended for my personal using. Up until now, I've been able to load that unpacked into the dev channel of chrome without the dev mode warning of the stable/beta channels. However, this feature will be removed [soon](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/05/continuing-to-protect-chrome-users-from.html) and I'm looking for ways to continue using this custom extension. According to the support page, it's possible via group policy, but I've been unable to do that since the extension lives locally on my hard drive and the `ExtensionInstallForcelist` in the policy requires an update url. I know I can pay the $5 reg fee  and publish the extension privately, but I do not want to pay for an extension that only I am using. Is there a way to load extension not from the chrome store into chrome, where the extension is only available locally on the hard drive? Simply loading it unpacked will give a "dev mode" warning every time chrome starts and that's annoying.

Comment: Why don't you load it unpacked with developer mode checked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enterprise deployment of Chrome extension on locked down Windows computers with no internet access to chrome web store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636428/enterprise-deployment-of-chrome-extension-on-locked-down-windows-computers-with)

Comment: To the automated comment above: you can write your own update XML and let the enterprise policy point to a local file as "update URL".

Comment: @gui47 Doing that would result in a developer mode warning every time chrome starts up.

Comment: @Xan According to that link, my pc needs to be connected to a domain. Is it possible to do that without having a domain? The extension is used on my personal machine. I did the steps in the link and it's not working with chrome `Version 44.0.2398.0 dev-m`

Comment: No. It's not possible. It's written that it's needed. It's written that it's needed because it's needed. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/23055651/934239

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reviewing [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions) on Google's Chrome Developer site if you haven't already. Hopefully, it'll be of some help.

The other alternatives are to pay the $5 **or** use a Google for Work account. GfW accounts are able to host apps for free if there only being made available to accounts within the domain. If you're not already using this type of account this won't be much help as they're about $5 a month + domain registration but I figured it was worth mentioning as an option :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try another [browser based on Chromium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29#Other_browsers_based_on_Chromium). Or Chromium itself. Or [Chromium Portable](http://crportable.sourceforge.net/) for specific moments related to the extension.